# Need some help from a web developer

Tags: html

So i found this html page that i'm planning to use as a start page, but i'd like to add the fav icons in front of links. I have no clue how to this so any help would be much appreciated.

So i found this html page that i'm planning to use as a start page, but i'd like to add the fav icons in front of links. I have no clue how to this so any help would be much appreciated.

```html
<!doctype:html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>&nbsp; Home</title>

    <link rel="icon" href="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.newdesignfile.com%2Fpostpic%2F2012%2F05%2Fwebsite-icon_337054.png">

<style>
#bg {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#home {
    color:white;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    /* margin-right: 30px; */
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 24px;
    }

.left { color: #FF4500 !important; }

#home > * {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0rem;
}

#home > * > div {
    padding: 10px;
}

#home > .left > div { text-align: right; }
#home > .right > div { text-align: left; }

a {
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    transition: 0.4s
}

a:active, a:focus { outline: 0; }

a:hover { color: violet; }

.slash { display: inline; color: yellow; }

</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="bg">
    <div id="home">
        <div class="left">
            <div>social</div>
            <div>media</div>
            <div>mail</div>
            <div>games</div>
            <div>opsys</div>
            <div>subreddits</div>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <div class="in"><a href="http://tweetdeck.com">twitter</a> <div class="slash">//</div> <a href="http://reddit.com">reddit</a></div>
            <div class="in"><a href="http://youtube.com">youtube</a> <div class="slash">//</div> <a href="http://twitch.tv">twitch</a></div>
            <div class="in"><a href="http://gmail.com">gmail</a> <div class="slash">//</div> <a href="http://outlook.com">outlook</a> <div class="slash">//</div> <a href="http://aol.com">aol</a></div>
            <div class="in"><a href="http://oldschool.runescape.com">osrs</a> <div class="slash">//</div> <a href="http://plazmaburst2.com">pb2</a></div>
            <div class="in"><a href="http://archlinux.org/">arch</a> <div class="slash">//</div> <a href="http://debian.org/">debian</a> <div class="slash">//</div> <a href="http://linux.org">linux</a></div>
            <div class="in"><a href="http://reddit.com/r/unixporn/">unixporn</a> <div class="slash">//</div> <a href="http://reddit.com/r/firefoxcss">firefoxcss</a> <div class="slash">//</div> <a href="http://reddit.com/r/i3wm">i3wm</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

....

Comment: What have you tried, and what problems are you having with your solution?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. If you want to add an image, you can do so using the <img> tag (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp). If you want to add an icon included as a font, you will need to link to the font assets on your page and use those. 

We'll need more information on exactly how you want to implement the icons, where they come from, what you've tried so far (and why it hasn't worked) and any other relevant details to provide an equally detailed and helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the code below in front of your external links and replace "website.com" with the website name (twitter.com for instance) whose icon you want to retrieve.

```
<img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=website.com">
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. btw how to make them a little bigger, let's say 110%?

Comment: You can specify the width and height of the icon within the <img> tag. For instance, width="15px" height="15px". Or you can use CSS to specify the width and height of images within the ".in" class.